# qemu-kvm connact install ubuntu 18.04 64 bit

Tags: apt, 18.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I try to install KVM with this [doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation)

But I have error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qemu-kvm : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (= 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.5)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What is I try:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils
```

or:

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get remove --purge libvirt-bin kvm qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils

apt-cache policy qemu-kvm qemu-system-x86
```

result:

```
qemu-kvm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.5
  Version table:
     1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.5 500
        500 http://mirror.rasanegar.com/ubuntu/archive bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.3 500
        500 http://mirror.rasanegar.com/ubuntu/archive bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7 500
        500 http://mirror.rasanegar.com/ubuntu/archive bionic/main amd64 Packages
qemu-system-x86:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.5
  Version table:
     1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.5 500
        500 http://mirror.rasanegar.com/ubuntu/archive bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.3 500
        500 http://mirror.rasanegar.com/ubuntu/archive bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7 500
        500 http://mirror.rasanegar.com/ubuntu/archive bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

and I try install with `synaptic` :(
can I install kvm ?

Comment: I would check your system is full upgraded; as the package your error shows is not current for Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic provides 7.8 & -updates provides 7.9 - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=qemu-system-x86)   Either you haven't full-upgraded; or you have non-Ubuntu source that has provided  qemu-kvm that requires older sources than your Ubuntu uses.

Comment: @guiverc What is the soultion?

Comment: You've not provided full output - but the output you provided was out-of-date (eg. bionic provides 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.8 or 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.9 with -updates), so I'm betting your qemu-kvm is not from Canonical/Ubuntu sources. I've suggest providing `apt-cache policy qemu-kvm qemu-system-x86` and it's output to your question   *ie. look at what non-official source is providing your problem*

Comment: @guiverc
I added the result

Comment: I had a look at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  and yes the mirror you provided is there but *last update unknown*.  I then compared the contents of what was in some of the directories for your mirror with the one I use (and some of your mirrors were EOL & shouldn't be there), and you have only a fraction of the *current* packages that were in my own chosen mirror. I'd suggest changing your source/mirror to the main, or another more regularly updated.  In my opinion your mirror is the problem and it needs change

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for you guid, my problem is solved plz answer to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is from comments -*

I would check your system is full upgraded; as the package your error shows is not current for Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic provides 7.8 & -updates provides 7.9 - packages.ubuntu.com/…) Either you haven't full-upgraded; or you have non-Ubuntu source that has provided qemu-kvm that requires older sources than your Ubuntu uses

*Mirror information was provided leading to -*

I had a look at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors and yes the mirror you provided is there but "*last update unknown*". I then compared the contents of what was in some of the directories for your mirror with the mirror I use (and some of your  mirror's packages were EOL & shouldn't be there [*more evidence of out-of-date state of mirror*]), and your mirror had only a fraction of the current packages that were in my own chosen mirror.

I'd suggest changing your source/mirror to the main, or another more regularly updated (*using aforementioned link*). In my opinion your mirror is the problem and it needs change.